# Link to another page in php pagination?

Tags: php, html

I have a code with query for in php paging

```
$page = (isset($_GET['page'])) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;

$startPoint = $page - 1;
$sql="SELECT * FROM ` admin_crmf_poc_event_history` 
where $condition
order by event_date asc
LIMIT $startPoint,30";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

and for creating link to next page, i use

```
<a href="index.php?page=<?php echo $page - 29?>">Prev</a>
<a href="index.php?page=<?php echo $page + 29?>">Next</a>
```

but I give link index.php which shows the whole values from the start.  dont know how to give link of next page so the rest of values are shown. Please help??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try it like this

```
$page = (isset($_GET['page']) && (int)$_GET['page']>0) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1);

$startPoint = ($page*30) - 30;
$sql="SELECT * FROM ` admin_crmf_poc_event_history` 
where $condition
order by event_date asc
LIMIT $startPoint,30";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

<?php if($page>1){?><a href="index.php?page=<?php echo $page - 1; ?>">Prev</a><?php } ?>
<a href="index.php?page=<?php echo $page + 1; ?>">Next</a>
```

so what I did is first I added `(int)` before your `$_GET['page']` to cast the `$_GET` value to `int`, second thing is I multiplied `$page` by how many rows per page you want then subtracted rows per page so, if you are at page 1 your start point will be `1*30-30=0` at page 2 it will be `2*30-30=30` etc... Then all you have to do with page links is subtract 1 for previous page and add 1 for next page.